# No me funciona boton de LogOut en C#

Tags: c#, html

Estoy haciendo un link para "Cerrar Sesion"

```
<li><a id="Logout" href="#" onclick="btLogOut" runat="server">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
```

y con el método

```
    public void btLogOut()
{
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Pero no me está funcionando, favor indicarme que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Hola, podrias especificar exactamente que ocurre cuando dices que no funciona?

Comment: @gbianchi no realiza ninguna función cuando hago el click

Comment: OK, solo aclara si el codigo se ejecuta, o no. Si es la segunda opcion, el boton esta bien linkeado al evento?

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu etiqueta `<a>` por `<asp:LinkButton>` para que quede así y puedas redireccionar al evento deseado:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogOut" runat="server" onclick="btLogOut">Cerrar Sesión</asp:LinkButton>
```

Si no te llegara a funcionar, en la línea que te pongo borra `btnLogOut` y dale `Ctrl + Barra espaciadora` y te mostrará una lista de los eventos disponibles para realizar el enlace con `public void btLogOut()`

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas

```
 System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

y también:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

pero al final rediriges tu página:

```
  Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Si vas a cerrar la sesión, es suficiente con `Session.Abandon()` al ejecutar el evento Click en tu botón:

```
public void btLogOut(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    Session.Abandon(); 
}
```

---

Es importante que para lograr la ejecución del método debes usar un `asp:Button`  :

```
<li><asp:Button id="Logout" href="#" OnClick="btLogOut" runat="server">Cerrar Sesión</asp:Button></li>
```

o un `asp:LinkButton` :

```
<li><asp:LinkButton id="Logout" href="#" OnClick="btLogOut" runat="server">Cerrar Sesión</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra que podés utilizar sería esta:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.User = null;
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

con tu código actual estás intentando llamar un evento del lado del cliente o sea codigo Javascript, para poder llamar codigo del lado del servidor debes usar un control del lado del servidor como asp:Linkbutton o asp:button tal y como está en otras respuestas.

O con el codigo actual, si no estoy mal puedes usar onserverclick="btLogOut"